# Script is executed even though xss is enabled

Tags: django, nginx, xss, csrf, nginx-config

I'm running my site on nginx server(1.12.2). I'm using django framework for my site.

I have enabled X-XSS protection in settings.py in django by,

```
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = TRUE
```

In nginx conf, I have added the headers to enable XSS protection.

In network tab, I can see the header types in response headers. But when i type a script in form(say an alert), the script is getting executed even though xss is enabled.

[image: Response Headers]

Comment: Scripts in forms have nothing to do with xss.

Answer (score 0):

The `X-XSS-Protection` header only deals with reflected XSS attacks.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection

It sounds like you want the browser to not execute any scripts at all? In which case I think...

`Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none';`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

Might do the trick.